# C a program to backup dot files

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

So I've written a small program to keep updating my dotfiles in another directory with a git repository. I just wanted to keep practising my C coding.

The program is a gross violation of the DRY principle and does not work either.
Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    FILE *files_from[7];
    files_from[0] = fopen(".vimrc", "r");
    files_from[1] = fopen(".profile", "r");
    files_from[2] = fopen(".tmux_conf", "r");
    files_from[3] = fopen(".zshrc", "r");
    files_from[4] = fopen(".bashrc", "r");
    files_from[5] = fopen(".bash_aliases", "r");
    files_from[6] = fopen(".gitconfig", "r");

    FILE *files_to[7];
    files_to[0] = fopen("dotFiles/.vimrc", "w");
    files_to[1] = fopen("dotFiles/.profile", "w");
    files_to[2] = fopen("dotFiles/.tmux.conf", "w");
    files_to[3] = fopen("dotFiles/.zshrc", "w");
    files_to[4] = fopen("dotFiles/.bashrc", "w");
    files_to[5] = fopen("dotFiles/.bash_aliases", "w");
    files_to[6] = fopen("dotFiles/.gitconfig", "w");


    for(int i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
    {
        int character;
        while( (character = fgetc(files_from[i])) != EOF)
        {
            fputc(character, files_to[i]); 
        }
    }



}
```

Why do I get a segmentation fault ?!
(Also anyway to keep it DRY?)

EDIT: You are all right. One of them was NULL. I just added an if statement before the while loop to check if the current file from either array is NULL.

NOW how can I make this DRY?

Comment: Run in a debugger to catch the crash in action.

Comment: you are not checking whether files_from[i] or files_to[i] are NULL before using them. May be one of them is NULL and it crashes when you access it.

Comment: It can be NULL if there is some error in opening the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possibilities in your code to get segfault. Since you are not checking any of the fopen(), one missing file will cause fgetc() to segfault. Same with fputc(). You can use ltrace to see exactly which library call caused the segfault.

Answer (score 1):

As other wrote, there're many possible reason for a SegFault.
Adding some error control will helps.

Regarding how to make it DRY, this is a possibility:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAX_PATH (50)
#define dim(x) (sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]))


static const char sFiles[][MAX_PATH] = {
  ".vimrc",
  ".profile",
  ".tmux_conf",
  ".zshrc",
  ".bashrc",
  ".bash_aliases",
  ".gitconfig", 
};
static const char sDestDir[] = {"dotFiles/"};



int main(void)
{
  long num = dim(sFiles);
  printf("Size: %lu \n", num);
  FILE *files_from;
  FILE *files_to;
  char destPath[MAX_PATH];
  int character;
  int s = 0;

  for (int i=0; i<num; i++) {
    errno = 0;
    printf("loop: %d\n",i);
    strncpy(destPath, sDestDir, MAX_PATH);
    files_from = fopen(sFiles[i], "r");
    if (files_from == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "File %s open failed: %s\n", sFiles[i], strerror(errno));
      continue;
    }
    strncat(destPath, sFiles[i], MAX_PATH);
    files_to = fopen(destPath, "w");
    if (files_to == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "File %s open failed: %s\n", destPath, strerror(errno));
      s = 0;
      s = fclose(files_from);
      if (EOF == s) {
        perror("Close Failed");
      }
      continue;
    }
    printf("Now Copying %s to %s\n", sFiles[i], destPath);
    while( (character = fgetc(files_from)) != EOF) {
      fputc(character, files_to);
    }
    s = 0;
    s = fclose(files_to);
    if (EOF == s) {
      perror("Close Failed");
    }
    s = 0;
    s = fclose(files_from);
    if (EOF == s) {
      perror("Close Failed");
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I've added some error control and the program keep working even if one of the file is missing.